# Calculation of activation maps spatial gradients in PyTorch

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a 4D tensor of activation maps, i.e., `X` of size `(bs, channels, dim, dim)`; e.g.,

```
import torch
bs = 3
channels = 512
dim = 64
X = torch.rand(bs, channels, dim, dim)
```

I want to calculate the (x, y)-gradients of the activation maps (which are roughly seen as "images"). I think that this can be done using a 2D convolution with fixed weights. For the x-gradient, for instance,

```
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn

grad_x_weights = np.array([[1, 0, -1],
                           [2, 0, -2],
                           [1, 0, -1]])
conv_x = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
conv_x.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.from_numpy(grad_x_weights).float().expand(1, 512, 3,3))

grad_x = conv_x(X)
```

This will (as expected) give an output of size `(3, 1, 64, 64)`, but what I would like to have is the gradient of the activation maps, for *each* activation map, so something of size `(3, 512, 64, 64)` in a way that `grad_x[i, j, :, :]` will have the x-gradient of the j-th activation map of the i-th input.

Finally, I would like to set `grad_x_weights` as non-learnable, so that `conv_x` will always calculates the gradients of the activation maps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

bs = 3
channels = 512
dim = 64
X = torch.rand(bs, channels, dim, dim)

grad_x_weights = torch.tensor([
    [1, 0, -1],
    [2, 0, -2],
    [1, 0, -1]
], dtype=torch.float32)
grad_x_weights = grad_x_weights.expand(channels, 1, 3, 3)

grad_x = F.conv2d(X, grad_x_weights, groups=X.shape[1], padding=1)
```

I am

1. Using `torch.nn.functional` version of [`conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d), since it is by default non-learnable
2. Using the `groups=in_channels` parameter which here means that each input channel is convolved *separately* to one output channel
3. Expanding the kernel along the first (`out_channels`) dimension to `channels` to maintain the same dimensionality of output